Angular Why Does ngIf always Negate to True
I hoping someone can explain this to me.  Why does the %ngIf as well as the else seem to always negate to true unless I'm doing something totally wrong.
This is the scenario:
I have a icon  if the array length is >=0 it will turn the background color to pink
else the background color of the icon will be white.
No matter how I change the scenario it still negates to true.  I deleted the array and the
icon still remained solid pink.  I added an else it would choose the else even the if *ngIf is true.  So, not sure what's going on here.
Here are some of the things I tried
          <span *ngIf="wishitems.length >=0" class="fas fa-heart float-right" aria- 
          hidden="true"></span>


        <span *ngIf="wishitems.length >=0" class="fas fa-heart float-right" aria- 
        hidden="true" ngIfElse="wishitems.length == -1" class="far fa-heart float-left" 
         aria-hide="true"></span>

         <span *ngIf="wishitems.length >=0" class="fas fa-heart float-right" aria- 
         hidden="true"></span>
    
          <span *ngIf="wishItems.length <0" class="far fa-heart float-right" aria- 
          hide="true"></span>

I recall reading some where that the *ngIf didn't like negative numbers.  Any help in
pointing me in the right direction would be great! Thanks in advance.

Start by printing the value of wishitems.length then print wishitems.length >= 0. You might figure it out from there. ngif that is true will NOT reach the else.

ngIfElse has no effect, Angular doesn't have such a directive, this is just some random attribute in the HTML. Also, I recommend you to do some basic tutorial on JavaScript arrays. It seems like you have serious misconceptions. For example, the length of an array is never negative.

@user2280852 please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated! stackblitz starter

I understand your confusion with the *ngIf directive in Angular.

Array length issue:
The length of an array is always a non-negative integer. It can be 0 (for an empty array) or any positive integer. It can never be negative. This means that wishitems.length >= 0 will always be true for any array, even an empty one.

Correct usage of *ngIf and else:
The syntax you're using for the else condition is incorrect. In Angular, you use a template reference for the else part.


Here's the correct way to implement what you're trying to achieve:
<ng-container *ngIf="wishitems.length > 0; else emptyWishlist">
  <span class="fas fa-heart float-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #emptyWishlist>
  <span class="far fa-heart float-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</ng-template>

This code does the following:

If wishitems.length > 0 (meaning there are items in the wishlist), it shows a solid heart icon.
If wishitems.length is 0 (meaning the wishlist is empty), it shows an outlined heart icon.

If you want to change the background color instead of changing the icon, you can use [ngClass] or [style.background-color]:
<span class="fa-heart float-right" 
      [ngClass]="{'fas': wishitems.length > 0, 'far': wishitems.length === 0}"
      [style.background-color]="wishitems.length > 0 ? 'pink' : 'white'"
      aria-hidden="true"></span>

This approach uses a single <span> and changes its class and background color based on the length of wishitems.
Remember:

Array length is always non-negative, so length >= 0 is always true.
Use length > 0 to check if an array has elements.
Use length === 0 to check if an array is empty.

Would you like me to explain any part of this solution in more detail?

Your first *ngIf works if wishitems is an array.
To test what's going on, change wishitems to an array of number like that:
wishitems: Array<number> = [1];

And your html to:
<span *ngIf="wishitems.length >=0" aria-hidden="true">Test</span>

Then you will start to see Test in your browser.

I want to thank everyone for their effort  n getting me on the correct path,  Rafiee 's answer is the accepted answer that work for me , uKn  helped me test  my array and figure out why it was empty.  I couldn't choose both as accepted answers. .  Thank you for your detailed explanations ,  I got a little side tracked with index and length.   I really appreciate your help so much, it works as expected! I tested it thoroughly

Restructure your *ngIf to handle the negation part as well. Currently, the truth scenario is being handled. Also, ensure the correct condition is also used to evaluate in the template.
Refer the code below:
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  <span class="far fa-heart float-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</ng-template>

<span *ngIf="wishitems.length > 0; else elseTemplate" class="fas fa-heart float-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>

